# Define memory size in OpenShift CLI

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

In OpenShift CLI, how can I define the memory size within the `oc new-app` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that `oc new-app` allows you to specify this on the command line. So your best bet would be to use `oc new-app` and then use `oc patch` to edit the created Deployment.

Alternatively, you can use `oc run` to start a single Pod, with that command you can actually specify `--limits` and `--requests`, but that is probably not what you want:

```
oc run ruby-hello-world --image=ruby-hello-world --limits=cpu=200m,memory=400Mi --requests=cpu=100m,memory=200Mi
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a new app using s2i build process. I have an image in dockerhub. During the assemble process I get an OOM kill due to a memory issue.